# Css First child

Tags: css, css-selectors

The tag first child instead of only changing the color of my first element changes all of them
http://codepen.io/asaf147369/pen/rjELxq

```
    nav ul li a {
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    nav ul li a:first-child
     {
        color:#00e0d0;
    }
```

any help?

Comment: anchor is always the first child of li .. you need to select li which is first child ... ie li:first-child

Answer (score 1):

you need to select li which is first child as anchor tag is always first child of every containing li .. so all 'a' tags are selected

```css
li:first-child a {
color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li><a> one </a></li>
  <li><a> one </a></li>
  <li><a> one </a></li>
  <li><a> one </a></li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select first `li` element not `a`:

```
nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}

nav ul li:first-child a {
    color:#00e0d0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are targetting the first `a` in an `li`.

Instead target the first `li`.

Like this:

```
nav ul li:first-child a {
   color: #00e0d0;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. You are selecting all `a` tags in any `li` tag where `a` is the first child. This solution selects all `a` tags in the first `li` tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the first `li`, not the first `a` inside every li:

```
nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
nav ul li:first-child a
 {
    color:#00e0d0;
}
```